# The file is not correct when decompress with tar -xvJf xxx.tar.xz?

Tags: tar

I was trying to "tar -xvJf binutil-3.6.1.tar.xz" then build it in a cross-compiling project.
But when I start the build I found some files such as regex.c (who has 8k+ lines) have lost some codes at the end of the file. It seems to happen in big files.
Does anyone know why and how to resolve this problem?
thanks.

tried:
tar -xvJf binutil-3.6.1.tar.xz
some files are Incomplete. (such as regex.c, elf.c, elflink.c, all of them are more than 5000 lines)

with the following cmd, the files were correct and no data was lost:
xz -d binutil-3.6.1.tar.xz
tar -xvf binutil-3.6.1.tar

the host is ubuntu18.04.

also tried with "right-click->Extract here", it seems no problem. So I think it only happens with tar -xvJf.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming. Maybe you meant to post on [superuser](https://superuser.com)